# Each scraped html tag values are inserted in multiple new rows in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-scraping

I am having a problem and I am totally stuck. My problem is that when I am
scraping a webpage and trying to insert the scraped content in mysql database,
each content is inserted in new rows for each html tag rather than inserting
into the same single row.  For example say a webpage has 10 span html tags then
mysql is taking 10 rows to insert the same content without inserting the whole
content into a single row.

```
<?php
        // this is the part of my code i am facing probleme

$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

 $describtion = $xpath->query('xpath will be here for example //span'); //xpath for all span
foreach ($describtion as $desc) {
    $content = $desc->nodeValue;

$sql=" INSERT INTO contents (content)
VALUES ('$content') ";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added"; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have  insert query inside your for loop

```
foreach ($describtion as $desc) {
    $content = $desc->nodeValue;

$sql=" INSERT INTO contents (content)
VALUES ('$content') ";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added"; 

}
```

Put it outside

```
$content="";
foreach ($describtion as $desc) {
        $content .= $desc->nodeValue;

    }
 $sql=" INSERT INTO contents (content)
    VALUES ('$content') ";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    echo "1 record added";
```